# Choosing a specific version in Git and moving it to a different branch

Tags: git

I have 6 versions of code 1,2,3,4,5,6 in development. There is a different branch for production which is tested version of development code. I want to promote version 4 to production today and at a later date version 6 to production.
How can I do this without moving any files manually.

Comment: by 6 versions you mean 6 branches or 6 different commits or what?

Comment: There are 6 different commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rebase your local repo, and then push to production branch.

```
git checkout <develop_branch>
git rebase <specific commit(4)>
git push -u origin production_branch_name
```

Then later again

```
git rebase <specific commit(6)>
git push -u origin production_branch_name
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common approaches for doing this

- Rebasing
- Merging

@m. aibin described the Rebasing approach.  Rebasing allows you to rewrite history and make the changes on the Development Branchlook like they were made on the Release Branch.  Some people like it better because it makes the final tree less "branchy".  Others don't like it because it muddies the true development history.  Also, people who are used to traditional version control often do not like rebasing.

The other approach is Merging where you promote a specific commit point from the Development Branch into the Release Branch.  The disadvantage of this approach is that it forces you to create additional commits on the Release Branch to do the merge.

For more info, read [Merging vs. Rebasing](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/)  Tutorial by Atlassian.  It shows both approaches.

Comment: "The disadvantage of this approach is that it forces you to create additional commits on the Release Branch to do the merge." This is not true when a fast forward merge is possible. A new commit is only created if the head of release branch is ahead of branching point of the feature branch, or if you merge with `--no-ff` option. Anyway, in the end a lot depends on established branching policy (you should have one and enforce it!). Personally, I always prefer a merge over rebase, as the latter is essentially lying to your version control and more prone to confusion.

Comment: @sendaran I generally use merging as well.  I also sync my repository to GitHub which I believe precludes the ability to fast forward or rebase on pushed commits.  I do occasionally use rebase to fix an oops on a commit.